# Where statement in Kibana search?

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

This is a typical log line from Apache being stored in AWS Elasticsearch. I'd like to be able to add a viz to my dashboard showing top referrers. The problem is that many static files have referrers from its own domain which prevents me from seeing the data I want.

Is it possible to have a search expression like "where REFERRER does not contain VHOST"

> 123.456.78.9 - - [15/Feb/2017:18:33:25 +0000] example.com "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 42766 "http://facebook.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A456 Safari/602.1" Server=aws8 SSL=- 8868 0
>
> 123.456.78.9 - - [15/Feb/2017:18:33:25 +0000] example.com "GET /js/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js HTTP/1.1" 200 42766 "http://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A456 Safari/602.1" Server=aws8 SSL=- 8868 0

Comment: how do you save the log? what are your fields?

Comment: @AliHashemi Did you read the post? I included two log lines...

Comment: @prophoto What you are showing above are the raw log lines and that gives no indication as to how they can be queried. We need to know the mapping of your referrer field and what data it contains exactly.

Comment: In the first log line referrer is "http://facebook.com/" second is "http://example.com/"

Comment: [ip, user, username, timestamp, vhost, request, status_code, bytes, referrer, browser, server, ssl, timems, times]